# Can't access Rails association in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm struggling to get an association to work properly in Rails. I'm just learning the language, so any help is really appreciated.

I have:

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :section
end


class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
    has_many :feedbacks
end
```

My 'feedbacks' table has a 'section_id' column.

Then in my /show.html.erb in sections I have:

```
<% @section.feedback.each do |feedback| %> 
  <%= feedback.name %> 
<% end %>
```

And I get the following error:

```
undefined method `feedback' for #<Section:0x007fa70dd2dc58>
Did you mean?  feedbacks
               feedbacks=
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try making the `feedbacks` plural?

```
<% @section.feedbacks.each do |feedback| %>
```

[Here's the link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) to `has_many` association.

Note that you pluralized it properly in the model definition.

Comment: I was sure I had tried that! That's done it, thank you.

Comment: No problem, Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with a `has_many` association, when referring to the associated class, you should always use the plural tense. In this case, `feedbacks` instead of `feedback`. Note that this is only true for this direction. If you were to try and find a feedback's section you would keep it singular: `@feedback.section`.